# Routing of Self-Hosted WCF Service

Tags: wcf, asp.net-routing

I have a self hosted WCF service that listens on port 80 (the third-party device does not support sending on other ports).  I also have two web sites and three Web API base services that are also on port 80 and have been working well.  All of these services/sites run using different FQDNs (test-svc1.example.com, test-svc2.example.com, test-site1.example.com, etc..).  It is important to note that all the subdomains point to the same IP Address on the server.  All of this has been working great until I try and install my service that hosts my WCF service.  Once I install that service when I attempt to navigate to either of my two sites I get a page with the following information on it:

.....

You have created a service.

To test this service, you will need to create a client and use it to call the service. You can do this using the svcutil.exe tool from the command line with the following syntax:

.....

If I stop my WCF based service then my site works fine.

The following is the code that is used to host the WCF service.
    public class MyService
    {
        private const string MyServiceName = "MyService";
        private ServiceHost _selfHost;

```
    public void Start()
    {
        this._selfHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyWebService), new Uri(wcf.exampe.com));

        try
        {
            BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
            int tempValue = 0;
            this._selfHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IMyServiceContract), binding, MyServiceName);

            ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
            smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;
            this._selfHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);

            this._selfHost.Open();

        }
        catch ( CommunicationException ce )
        {
            this._selfHost.Abort();
        }
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        // Close the ServiceHostBase to shutdown the service.
        this._selfHost.Close();

    }
}
```

This code is called by a windows service wrapper.  What I need is for this service to be able to run on port 80, but only listen for packets associated with wcf.example.com.

---------  EVENT VIEWER Information

I have enabled debugging and tracing in the Event Viewer to see if that would help me isolate the issue.  The following is are a few of the items from there.

```
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
    <System>
        <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-Application Server-Applications" Guid="{c651f5f6-1c0d-492e-8ae1-b4efd7c9d503}" /> 
        <EventID>57396</EventID> 
        <Version>0</Version> 
        <Level>3</Level> 
        <Task>0</Task> 
        <Opcode>0</Opcode> 
        <Keywords>0x2000000000010000</Keywords> 
        <TimeCreated SystemTime="2013-08-16T20:52:13.956945800Z" /> 
        <EventRecordID>99</EventRecordID> 
        <Correlation ActivityID="{1E2ADE87-F4FC-4B42-8711-DD49B2F0DB6B}" /> 
        <Execution ProcessID="1716" ThreadID="4828" ProcessorID="0" KernelTime="0" UserTime="3" /> 
        <Channel>Microsoft-Windows-Application Server-Applications/Analytic</Channel> 
        <Computer>MyComputer</Computer> 
        <Security UserID="S-1-5-18" /> 
    </System>
    <EventData>
        <Data Name="data1">System.ServiceModel 4.0.0.0</Data> 
        <Data Name="data2">System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException: There is a problem with the XML that was received from the network. See inner exception for more details. ---> System.Xml.XmlException: The body of the message cannot be read because it is empty. --- End of inner exception stack trace ---</Data> 
        <Data Name="SerializedException">
            <Exception>
                <ExceptionType>System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException, System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
                </ExceptionType>
                <Message>There is a problem with the XML that was received from the network. See inner exception for more details.
                </Message>
                <StackTrace> at System.Runtime.Diagnostics.EtwDiagnosticTrace.WriteExceptionToTraceString(XmlTextWriter xml, Exception exception, Int32 remainingLength, Int32 remainingAllowedRecursionDepth) at System.Runtime.Diagnostics.EtwDiagnosticTrace.ExceptionToTraceString(Exception exception, Int32 maxTraceStringLength) at System.Runtime.Diagnostics.EtwDiagnosticTrace.GetSerializedPayload(Object source, TraceRecord traceRecord, Exception exception, Boolean getServiceReference) at System.Runtime.TraceCore.ThrowingException(EtwDiagnosticTrace trace, String param0, String param1, Exception exception) at System.Runtime.ExceptionTrace.TraceException[TException](TException exception, String eventSource) at System.Runtime.ExceptionTrace.AsError(Exception exception) at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpPipeline.EnqueueMessageAsyncResult.CompleteParseAndEnqueue(IAsyncResult result) at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpPipeline.EnqueueMessageAsyncResult.HandleParseIncomingMessage(IAsyncResult result) at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.SyncContinue(IAsyncResult result) at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpPipeline.EnqueueMessageAsyncResult..ctor(ReplyChannelAcceptor acceptor, Action dequeuedCallback, HttpPipeline pipeline, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpPipeline.EmptyHttpPipeline.BeginProcessInboundRequest(ReplyChannelAcceptor replyChannelAcceptor, Action dequeuedCallback, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelListener`1.HttpContextReceivedAsyncResult`1.ProcessHttpContextAsync() at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelListener`1.BeginHttpContextReceived(HttpRequestContext context, Action acceptorCallback, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SharedHttpTransportManager.EnqueueContext(IAsyncResult listenerContextResult) at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SharedHttpTransportManager.OnGetContextCore(IAsyncResult listenerContextResult) at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SharedHttpTransportManager.OnGetContext(IAsyncResult result) at System.Runtime.Fx.AsyncThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(IAsyncResult result) at System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.Complete(IntPtr userToken) at System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.ProtectedInvokeCallback(Object result, IntPtr userToken) at System.Net.ListenerAsyncResult.IOCompleted(ListenerAsyncResult asyncResult, UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes) at System.Net.ListenerAsyncResult.WaitCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped) at System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* pOVERLAP)
                </StackTrace>
                <ExceptionString>System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException: There is a problem with the XML that was received from the network. See inner exception for more details. ---&amp;gt; System.Xml.XmlException: The body of the message cannot be read because it is empty. --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
                </ExceptionString>
                <InnerException>
                    <Exception>
                        <ExceptionType>System.Xml.XmlException, System.Xml, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
                        </ExceptionType>
                        <Message>The body of the message cannot be read because it is empty.
                        </Message>
                        <StackTrace> at System.Runtime.Diagnostics.EtwDiagnosticTrace.WriteExceptionToTraceString(XmlTextWriter xml, Exception exception, Int32 remainingLength, Int32 remainingAllowedRecursionDepth) at System.Runtime.Diagnostics.EtwDiagnosticTrace.GetInnerException(Exception exception, Int32 remainingLength, Int32 remainingAllowedRecursionDepth) at System.Runtime.Diagnostics.EtwDiagnosticTrace.WriteExceptionToTraceString(XmlTextWriter xml, Exception exception, Int32 remainingLength, Int32 remainingAllowedRecursionDepth) at System.Runtime.Diagnostics.EtwDiagnosticTrace.ExceptionToTraceString(Exception exception, Int32 maxTraceStringLength) at System.Runtime.Diagnostics.EtwDiagnosticTrace.GetSerializedPayload(Object source, TraceRecord traceRecord, Exception exception, Boolean getServiceReference) at System.Runtime.TraceCore.ThrowingException(EtwDiagnosticTrace trace, String param0, String param1, Exception exception) at System.Runtime.ExceptionTrace.TraceException[TException](TException exception, String eventSource) at System.Runtime.ExceptionTrace.AsError(Exception exception) at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpPipeline.EnqueueMessageAsyncResult.CompleteParseAndEnqueue(IAsyncResult result) at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpPipeline.EnqueueMessageAsyncResult.HandleParseIncomingMessage(IAsyncResult result) at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.SyncContinue(IAsyncResult result) at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpPipeline.EnqueueMessageAsyncResult..ctor(ReplyChannelAcceptor acceptor, Action dequeuedCallback, HttpPipeline pipeline, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpPipeline.EmptyHttpPipeline.BeginProcessInboundRequest(ReplyChannelAcceptor replyChannelAcceptor, Action dequeuedCallback, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelListener`1.HttpContextReceivedAsyncResult`1.ProcessHttpContextAsync() at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelListener`1.BeginHttpContextReceived(HttpRequestContext context, Action acceptorCallback, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SharedHttpTransportManager.EnqueueContext(IAsyncResult listenerContextResult) at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SharedHttpTransportManager.OnGetContextCore(IAsyncResult listenerContextResult) at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SharedHttpTransportManager.OnGetContext(IAsyncResult result) at System.Runtime.Fx.AsyncThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(IAsyncResult result) at System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.Complete(IntPtr userToken) at System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.ProtectedInvokeCallback(Object result, IntPtr userToken) at System.Net.ListenerAsyncResult.IOCompleted(ListenerAsyncResult asyncResult, UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes) at System.Net.ListenerAsyncResult.WaitCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped) at System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* pOVERLAP)
                        </StackTrace>
                        <ExceptionString>System.Xml.XmlException: The body of the message cannot be read because it is empty.
                        </ExceptionString>
                    </Exception>
                </InnerException>
            </Exception>
        </Data> 
        <Data Name="AppDomain">MyService.exe</Data> 
    </EventData>
</Event>
```

----------------- End Error

The transport sent a message to 'http://x.x.x.8/data/MyService'.

Handling an exception.  Exception details: System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException: There is a problem with the XML that was received from the network. See inner exception for more details. ---> System.Xml.XmlException: The body of the message cannot be read because it is empty.
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpPipeline.EnqueueMessageAsyncResult.CompleteParseAndEnqueue(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpPipeline.EnqueueMessageAsyncResult.HandleParseIncomingMessage(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.SyncContinue(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpPipeline.EnqueueMessageAsyncResult..ctor(ReplyChannelAcceptor acceptor, Action dequeuedCallback, HttpPipeline pipeline, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpPipeline.EmptyHttpPipeline.BeginProcessInboundRequest(ReplyChannelAcceptor replyChannelAcceptor, Action dequeuedCallback, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelListener`1.HttpContextReceivedAsyncResult`1.ProcessHttpContextAsync()

HttpGetContext start.

---------  EVENT VIEWER Information

As mentioned before, all of this works fine on my test box when running under Visual Studio, but does not work when run on my production box as a service.

Regards,

Richard O

Comment: I was able to get a response on how to solve this from another forum.  For those of you that are interested in how to solve something like this please see the following: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/23a6dcd5-c4a8-43ab-a4f2-7be96d9047f9/routing-of-selfhosted-wcf-service

Comment: This question has been resolved.  Not sure how to show that since I cannot answer my own question.